# Fiddler QuickExec for gateway settings

Tags: proxy, fiddler, wininet

[image: WinInetProxy]

Is there any way to set fiddler to lookup gateway proxy (upstream proxy) from **Advanced** configuration instead of the common configuration? I have an application that sets multiple proxies for each protocol. So fiddler assumes there is no gateway unless it finds something in the box above.

Also is there any QuickExec command available for changing the Gateway? I'm looking for rapid way to set upstream proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the upstream gateway for each session is inherited from the IE/Windows default proxy setting that was set when Fiddler starts up.

However, on each session it can be overridden using the `X-OverrideGateway` Session Flag.

So, to build your own QuickExec action, do this:

Inside Rules > Customize Rules > `Handlers`, add

```
public static var m_GatewayOverride = null;
```

Inside `OnBeforeRequest`, add

```
if (null != m_GatewayOverride) { oSession["X-OverrideGateway"] = m_GatewayOverride;
```

Inside the `OnExecAction` method's `switch` statement, add

```
case "gw":
    if (sParams.Length<2) {m_GatewayOverride = null; return;}
    m_GatewayOverride = sParams[1]; FiddlerObject.StatusText="Set Gateway to " + m_GatewayOverride;
    return true;
```

Then, you can type things like `gw myProxy:1234` to force subsequent requests to `myProxy:1234` or simply type `gw` to clear the override.

Comment: I don't understand "the first issue." Fiddler picks up the proxy settings from WinINET, regardless of whether they're in the "Advanced" configuration or not. What settings do you think aren't being picked up, and what leads you to believe that? Thanks!